# Markup Validation for asp.net aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, validation

I created a website using asp.net. Before launching the website on the internet I wanted to do a validation test on the web forms I used.  I already know of how to validate the HTML"Static Websites", by going  W3C Markup Validation Service. Is it possible to do the same validation methodology on Webforms.aspx by upldoading the files? If its ok, how to initial the validation process?!

Thank you.

Comment: What benefit would this provide? Just validate the static markup that your .aspx pages generate. VS will also provide warnings when it detects invalid markup or undocumented attributes.

Comment: This may interest you http://users.skynet.be/mgueury/mozilla/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run a static validation directly against dynamic content, because dynamic content is well dynamic!

That said, for your scenario, load your application in a browser.  Then at various points, save the html markup (ie File -> Save in your browser) and then run the static validation on the saved markup.  So it might be interesting to save the form when empty, when use entered bad values, and after the form has been submitted.